# when a setter in a lib will be called in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, setter

I am having a doubt

In my lib folder i am having a file1.rb which has all some common methods kept under a module..

I am having a setter

```
              def a=(ab)
                   self.name == ab if ab
              end
```

I have included this file1.rb in my model by

include file1

my doubt is how this setter is getting called will this be called automatically as i have mentioned in model ..

Answer (score 0):

By including the module on the model, all it's methods become accessible from it.
It would be the same as defining the method directly on your model.
So, you should be able to call it from wherever you want.